Which Visual Studio build tools component provides Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props?
Which Visual Studio Build Tools component provides file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"?

Visual Studio's "Desktop development with C++" workload includes the Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props file. Make sure you have "MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools" installed.
